# My view in Oracle when displayed in ArcMap/ArcCatalog values are being dropped to 0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, oracle-dbms

I created a view in an Oracle Database in order to match formatting of a new database/table I am going to be migrating the data to.

The problem is when I look at my view in Oracle I see the correct values (at least values that I expected to see). However, when I bring the view into both ArcMap and ArcCatalog through the add data or database connection those values turn to zeros.

Does anyone have any thoughts?
I am using arc10 and SQL Developer

Comment: I was able to get this resolved. The connection to the database was set up in ODBC. I changed it to OLE DB and all values are correct.

Comment: Please be sure to transfer the content of your Comment to an Answer that you can then (or a little later) Accept to get your now resolved question moved off the Unanswered list.